# Ubuntu 14.04 - Cloning/copying an entire disk image?

Tags: linux, vps, ubuntu-14.04

Without going into too much detail, a certain popular VPS provider has been hacked and ddos'd.  The hack is the final straw but I am stuck on how to migrate and restore an entire image.

I'm currently using Ubuntu 14.04.  I want to migrate to either Digital Ocean or OVH.  What is the best way to snapshot then download an entire image that can be easily restored on another provider?

Comment: Are you running LVM? Does your current provider provide a rescue system? What is your partition layout?

Comment: KVM and its 24064 MB, ext4.  512 MB Swap

Answer (score 0):

To be honest with you, from one software layer (VPSx) to other software layer (VPSn) you will need to make a lot of efforts. Try to avoid the virtual machine layer. Focus to the service and data layer. Try to rebuild the same environment in the destination side. It will avoid frustration and losing time.

I did already using rsync @hostA to hostB.
The down time to the Host A will be minimal and DATA loss will be ZERO.

You will need to WIPE the HostA only after your HostB get ready to go.

rsync [-options] SOURCE user@x.x.x.x:DESTINATION

For full usage, check this link below.
https://www.atlantic.net/cloud-hosting/how-to-use-rsync-copy-sync-files-servers/